# revit-API：How to get the "Offset" in the "View Range" in the "Plan Region"?

Tags: c#, revit-api, autodesk, revitpythonshell

**my idea**

1. I tried to use "SetViewRange" to get "View Range" in "Plan Region",
   but "Plan Region" is not "View Plane", only "ViewPlane" can use
   "SetViewRange" method, so this idea failed.
2. There is a parameter named "View Range" in the "Parameter" of the
   "Plane Region", and the "offset value" I want is not found in the
   parameter "View Range",so this idea failed.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `GetViewRange` method of your plan `View`, in conjuctnion with the `PlanViewPlane` object:
https://www.revitapidocs.com/2019/80d20187-97ea-f6c0-a3a8-d5545e0b3863.htm

So to get the Offsets looks something like this:

```
view = uidoc.ActiveView # the plan youre wanting to investigate

topOffset = view.GetViewRange().GetOffset(PlanViewPlane.TopClipPlane) # Top Offset    
cutOffset = view.GetViewRange().GetOffset(PlanViewPlane.CutPlane) # Cut plane Offset    
bottomOffset = view.GetViewRange().GetOffset(PlanViewPlane.BottomClipPlane) # Bottom Offset
```

Answer (score 0):

the above view needs to be cast as ViewPlan:

```
ViewPlan view = uidoc.ActiveView as ViewPlan;
```